# How to add new Access record by checkbox and number of different date?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2016

I have query 1 or table 1 have the below data

```
Number of employee/start date/end date/code/different date by Days/checkbox
```

Example

```
200/01-01-2021/15-01-2021/E/14/Yes
```

I need when checkbox=Yes to open 14 record automatically in new table 2 with code like below:

```
 employee/date/code
 200/01-01-2021/E
 200/02-01-2021/E
 200/03-01-2021/E
 200/04-01-2021/E
 200/05-01-2021/E
 200/06-01-2021/E
 200/07-01-2021/E
 200/08-01-2021/E
 200/09-01-2021/E
 200/10-01-2021/E
 200/11-01-2021/E
 200/12-01-2021/E
 200/13-01-2021/E
 200/14-01-2021/E
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract your parameters:

```vb
Data = "200/01-01-2021/15-01-2021/E/14/Yes"

ENo = Split(Data, "/")(0)
FirstDate = DateValue(Split(Data, "/")(1))
ECode = Split(Data, "/")(3)
Periods = Split(Data, "/")(4)
```

Then run this query passing it the parameters:

```sql
PARAMETERS 
    Periods Short, 
    FirstDate DateTime;
SELECT DISTINCT 
    10 * Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) + Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10) + 1 AS Sequence, 
    ENo As Employee, 
    DateAdd("d", [Sequence] - 1, [FirstDate]) AS DateStart, 
    ECode As Code
FROM 
    MSysObjects AS Uno, 
    MSysObjects AS Deca
WHERE 
    (10 * Abs([Deca].[id] Mod 10) + Abs([Uno].[id] Mod 10)) < [Periods];
```

Output:

[image]

You can the use this query as source in an append query.

Or, alternatively, use *DAO* to directly append the records:

```vb
Dim Records As DAO.Recordset
Dim Index   As Integer

Set Records = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * From Table2")

For Index = 0 To Periods - 1
    Records.AddNew
        Records!Employee.Value = Eno
        Records!Date.Value = DateAdd("d", Index, FirstDate)
        Records!Code.Value = ECode
    Records.Update
Next
Records.Close
```